# Raise User Defined Exception in django Web app from models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my models.py file

```
class DiskDrive(models.Model):
    deviceId = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
    freeSpace = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deviceId


class StoragePool(models.Model):
    poolId = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
    size = models.BigIntegerField()
    freeSpace = models.BigIntegerField()
    drive = models.ForeignKey(DiskDrive, related_name='pools')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.poolId

class DriveFull(Exception):
    STD_MESSAGE = 'Not enough free space in the selected Drive'
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = DriveFull.STD_MESSAGE
        self.resp()

    def resp(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        return render(request,'sim/error_detail.html',
                     {'drive_name' : "a",
                      'error_message' : "The selected drive doesn't have desired free space to create the Storage Pool.",})
    #def __str__(self):
         #   return self.msg

@receiver(pre_save,sender=StoragePool)
def check_drive_space(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if(instance.drive.freeSpace<instance.size):
        raise DriveFull
        #render_to_response("sim/error_detail.html", {"error_message": "The selected drive doesn't have desired free space to create the Storage Pool."})
........
```

My admin.py

```
....
admin.site.register(DiskDrive)
admin.site.register(StoragePool)
```

& thus Django Provides its default web pages to do opertions.

Now, I want to raise the User Defined Exception in Django, when anybody tries to create storage pool in the drive having no sufficient space.
I followed this link from stackoverflow.com =>[Django: User-defined exception not being caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641114/django-user-defined-exception-not-being-caught)

I created DriveFull(Exception) class & tried to do that, but it shows the Yellow Stack Trace page of Django on the browser & showing the error message in that page.
But I want to render this message on .html page I created.
Can somebody please tell me how to do so?
Thanks in advance.
     I got the following Traceback on browser:

```
DriveFull at /admin/sim/storagepool/add/
No exception message supplied
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/sim/storagepool/add/
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: DriveFull
Exception Location: F:\Project Python\My_Project\storagesim\sim\models.py in check_drive_space,      line 54
Python Executable:  C:\Python33\python.exe
Python Version: 3.3.2
```

Comment: Why not just catch this as a form validation?

Comment: Exception is to be notified on Web page provided by Django, on registering the urls @ admin site.I'm not creating the my own form.

Comment: Ok, so put the validation at the model level: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects